# Dynamically check checkbox in gridview depending on data returned from DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

If the value in column 9 is 49, I would like to check the checkbox.

```
Protected Sub grdMyGrid1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdMyGrid.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.Cells(9).Text = "49" Then
       ---- some code here -------
    End If

End Sub
```

Column in the gridview for the checkbox:

```
                        <asp:TemplateField >
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ckMyCheckbox" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done directly in your aspx file:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckMyCheckbox" runat="server"
          Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DBColumnName") == 49 %>'
/>
```

This is assuming DBType is Int, if it is a string, use `"49"`.

Comment: I'm receiving a compiler error message:  BC30201: Expression expected.
My expression is:  Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyColumn") == 49 %>'

Comment: is the value of type INT? and does this column have null values?